# How can I update the initial state from a useState from a axios.get return

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, axios

there! Well, I'm trying to build a update page to my personal project, on that page, i'd like to have all the information about a specfic spot. I'm storing the informations on a MongoDB cluster and getting it with a axios.get request.

Let me explain it better:

```
export default function({ history }) {

    window.data = {}
    const url = window.location.href.slice(-24)

    useEffect(() => {
        async function setParams() {
            const { data } = await api.get(`/spots/${url}`)

            console.log(data)
            window.data = data
            }
            setParams()
        }, [url]) 

        console.log(window.data)

//I'd like to put the window.data data inside of this 
//useStates, so I will display into the form inputs the 
//previous information to the user update it in the backend. 

        const [thumbnail, setThumbnail] = useState(null)<---
        const [company, setCompany] = useState('')<---
        const [price, setPrice] = useState('')<---
        const [techs, setTechs] = useState('')<---


    const preview = useMemo(() => {
        return thumbnail ? URL.createObjectURL(thumbnail) : null;
    }, [thumbnail])

    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        const data = new FormData()
        const user_id = localStorage.getItem('user')

        data.append('thumbnail', thumbnail)
        data.append('company', company)
        data.append('techs', techs)
        data.append('price', price)

        await api.put(`/updates/${url}`, data, { new: true })

        history.push('/dashboard')
    }
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label 
            id='thumbnail' 
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${preview})` }}
            className={thumbnail ? 'has-thumbnail' : ''}
            >
                <input type='file' onChange={event => setThumbnail(event.target.files[0])}/>
                <img src={camera} alt='Select img' />
            </label>

            <label htmlFor="company">EMPRESA *</label>
            <input
                id="company"
                placeholder="Sua empresa"
                value={company}//I'd like to fill this inputs with the information that I got from the get request.
                onChange={event => setCompany(event.target.value)}
            />

            <label htmlFor="company">TECNOLOGIAS *<span>(separadas por vírgula)</span></label>
            <input
                id="techs"
                placeholder="Tenologias utilizadas"
                value={techs}
                onChange={event => setTechs(event.target.value)}
            />

            <label htmlFor="company">PREÇO *</label>
            <input
                id="price"
                placeholder="Valor por dia"
                value={price}
                onChange={event => setPrice(event.target.value)}
            />

            <button type='submit' className='btn'>Cadastrar</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

What I know about this is that I need to render the page or at least the useStates AFTER getting the request. I've tried many ways to do it but nothing worked.

Shoud I put everything inside a class and use Async/Await?? I don't know how to change this code to it.

Comment: I guess you can call in `useEffect()` after `axios` returned the data for example `setThumbnail` or `setPrice` whichever is needed in your case which will set the value of `thumbnail` or `price` states.

Comment: But how will I use the values after it? Won't they get locked into useEffect scope?

Comment: No, they won't. So technically changing state in `useEffect()` is totally fine, you will be able to access the modified state in `render` still. I suggest to read the following: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Comment: but `useEffect` has an arrow function inside it, so it creates it's own scope.

Comment: @WennlysOliveira yes, and the `useState`  updater functions are in the scope of the functional component, so they can be called by anything else in the same scope.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt' get it.